# Condition for function to increase.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Question:**

> $f(x)=cos|x|-2ax+b$ increases for all $x\in \mathbb R$, then
>
> $(A)\;a\le b\qquad(b)\;a=b/2\qquad(C)\;a\le -1/2\qquad(D)\;a\ge-3/2$
>
> > Answer: C

**Doubt:**

For $f(x)$ to be increasing, shoudn't $f'(x)\gt0$, $\forall\;x\in \mathbb R$.

But in the solution, $f'(x)\ge0$. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implications hold for any differentiable function $f$:

- If $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, then $f$ is nondecreasing.
- If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, then $f$ is **strictly** increasing.
- If $f$ is nondecreasing, then $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

The first two assertions are easily proven using the mean value theorem. The third one follows from the definition of the derivative.

It is debatable whether the question asks for a nondecreasing or a strictly increasing function, as the word "increasing" could mean both. But the important part is that in both cases we have $f'(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: Ok, so unless it is stated in the question that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, we always take it to be non-decreasing?

Comment: I have added a paragraph to explain this further.

Comment: How is $f'(x)\ge 0$ in case of strictly increasing?

Comment: If $f$ is nondecreasing (or strictly increasing), then for $h \ne 0$ we have $(f(x + h) - f(x))/h \ge 0$. But this implies that $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I think I am getting confused. Do you mean that every strictly increasing function is non-decreasing. So If f is non-decreasing (or strictly increasing), then f′(x)≥0.

Comment: Yes. And that's the part that matters, because the question doesn't ask for a condition that is equivalent to the monotonicty of $f$. If only asks which condition is necessary to have monotonicity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x) \geq 0$ and $f'(x)=0$ only for finitely many points in any closed interval then $f$ is strictly increasing.

The reason is the following: Let $a <b$. Then $f'$ has only finitely many zeroes $x_1< ..< x_n$ strictly between $a$ and $b$.

By the mean value theorem $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,x_1,], [x_1,x_2],.., [x_n,b]$ and hence
$$f(a) <f(x_1) < ..<f(b)$$

Therefore $f(a) <f(b)$.

Comment: Ok, so this means that even if $f'(x)$ becomes 0 at some different points, then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing but if $f'(x)$ becomes 0 in an interval, then it becomes non-decreasing. Am I right?

Comment: @Cheapstrike Yes. Note that the proof above works as long as between any two points you can find an interval where $f'$ is not vanishing.